# Integration of the Pendo SDK with the .NET MAUI sample application causes an error

Tags: nuget, maui, .net-maui, pendo, maui-compat

One of our production applications which developed in Xamarin cross platform UI mobile framework, we have been using Pendo-sdk-ios and pendo-sdk-android nuget packages successfully.

https://support.pendo.io/hc/en-us/articles/4404246699419-Developer-s-Guide-to-Installing-the-Pendo-Xamarin-iOS-SDK

Now we are upgrading our xamarin application to .NET MAUI. I am facing an issue, while integrating Pendo-sdk packages with .NET MAUI Appliction.

Here are the steps to reproduce this issue:

A new sample MAUI .NET application has been created, and it has successfully run.

**iOS Platform**

I added pendo-sdk-ios nuget package version 2.16.0.5665(latest stable version).

I can use the Pendo package in the AppDelegate, the following code does not throw an error.

```
   using Pendo;
```

I am trying to initialize the Pendo SDK in the AppDelegate, however I am getting the following error.

```
    string pendo_app_key = "eyJhbGci…<KEY_HERE>";
    PendoManager.SharedManager().Setup(pendo_app_key);
    PendoManager.SharedManager().SetDebugMode(true);

.../CheckingPendo/Platforms/iOS/AppDelegate.cs(22,22): Error CS0012: The type 'NSObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. (CS0012) (CheckingPendo)
```

I am experiencing the same compile time error after adding Xamarin.ios reference as well.

```
​​<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-ios'">
      <PackageReference Include="pendo-sdk-iOS" Version="2.16.0.5665" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

**Android Platform**

After adding the pendo-sdk-android nuget package version 2.16.1.4053(latest stable version).
I am getting the following error.
​​

```
/Users/[user]/.nuget/packages/xamarin.android.support.annotations/28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.targets(3,3): Error MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly /Users/[user]/.nuget/packages/xamarin.android.support.annotations/28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
 Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. (MSB4062) (CheckingPendo)
```

I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: I have checked all the packages you provided with it's reference and dependencies. They all not support .net 6. So you could not use it in Maui.

Comment: Accepted answer is not relevant any more please look:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74520296/1790912

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pendo has released support for maui:
[Pendo Maui Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pendo-maui)
Instruction could be found [here](https://github.com/pendo-io/pendo-mobile-ios/blob/master/pnddocs/maui.md)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all the packages you provided with it's reference and dependencies. They are all not support .net 6. So you could not use it in Maui.

Answer (score 0):

Pendo SDK does not currently support MAUI, but they most likely will.